# Use JavaScript to crawl a website -> Possible and which IP is shown on the crawled site

Tags: javascript, angular, web-crawler

it is possible to crawl a website within an Angular-App? I am speaking about to call a website from Angular, not crawling an Angular-App. If that so, then I am wondering which IP will be shown on the crawled website. Since JavaScript is client-side, I would suggest, its the IP of the client, not of the server (like probably at nodejs). But all I know, its mostly browser-implemented stuff what we can use in JS, so it is even possible to crawl websites with methods from JavaScript (or Angular)?

Best Regards
Buzz

Comment: you probably cant because of cors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, you can create an AJAX request to fetch the data with reponse type `text/html`. That would give you the remote document as a string. The browser wouldn't try to load the JavaScript and CSS in that document, though. That might not be a problem but CORS is. For security reasons, most browsers prevent you from loading data from somewhere else (otherwise, it would be too easy for criminals to put JavaScript into any web page). See here for details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

If you have control over the second domain, you can configure the server there to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers to the browser to allow access from the Angular App.

Note: You could use an `iframe` to load the other website but when the domains of the current document and the one in the `iframe` don't match, then you can't access the contents of the `iframe` from JavaScript.

One way to work around this is to install a proxy on your server. The browser can then ask your server for the pages in question. In this case, the remote web site will get the IP of your server.

Comment: Thank you for the verbose response. So I let the crawling job doing by a java-backend and use a proxy to hide the server ip. then I pass the data via JSON to my Angular-App.